# Incorrect points showing as flash message in the achievements

Tags: bug, notifications, achievements-dialog

A few times (2 month duration) I noticed that there is a mismatch in the points notified in recent achievements as a flash message and what the real points inside it are.

Just a few minutes back when I opened Stack Overflow, I had a notification of 18 points. But the moment I clicked on it, it became 10 points (one upvote for my answer; there are no vote down or anything else).

This is not the first time it has occurred. Since it happened unexpectedly I couldn't take a screenshot for proof. It seems like a bug.

Comment: This *probably* isn't a bug. The most likely explanation for what you're seeing is "stale" information in the top bar. When you click on it, it fetches the latest, live information, so you see the points change. An example of a case where this might happen would be if someone inadvertently upvoted one of your answers, and then cleared it within the grace period.

Comment: @CodyGray: But I didn't have SO open in any of the browser session. This cases happened when a fresh browser session started.  So from where the stale data come?  If the data is fetched doesn't it have to be fresh?